# What is the difference between "with" and "within"?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

I'm working on a text and need to tell the users about the differences of certain options. I'm struggling between `with` and `within` and don't know which is the correct one for:

> 1. **With** this option you will add only your company name but won't have...
> 2. **Within** this option you will add only your company name  but won't have...

Which one is correct?

**Edit**: My native language is German and I've got the habit to think the sentence first in German and translate it then to English. In German you would be able to use "**Mit** dieser Option" or "**In** dieser Option" which are by meaning the same as Mit=With and In(close to)= Within. I checked some dictionaries and googled it as well, but couldn't find anything which would give me an idea of the correct answer for this context.

Comment: Have you looked up `with` and `within` in a dictionary? If so, please quote their definitions, and what you think the right answer is (and why). That will help us answer your question more specifically, and will also demonstrate that this question isn't a 'dictionary lookup' question, which is off-topic on ELL.

Comment: *Within* is "in" in the sense "inside of" = "innerhalb von", "binnen"

Comment: @ StoneyB Thanks, I will go for "with" than. :)

Comment: @Teo "In" is OK, but I prefer "with". Allow me, by the way, to recommend [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/), a multilingual dictionary supported with a large database of 'official' translations. It's heavy on bureaucratic uses, but valuable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The preposition *within* has nothing to do with the ordinary sense of the preposition *with* = “accompanying, alongside, by means of, etc.”. *Within* means “inside” in spatial, temporal and figurative senses.

> The hoard was discovered deep ***within*** the mound.
> You must respond to this communication ***within*** thirty days.
> They are ***within*** their rights in refusing to be interviewed.

Consequently, *within* is not a valid translation of German *in* in this context. However, English does support both German uses: you may use either *with* for *mit* or *in* for *in*.

> With this option ...
> In this option ...

- HISTORICAL NOTE, for those who wonder why the compound *with* + *in* has this meaning:

  Old English *wið* (cognate with German *wider*) originally meant “against, by, back from”, and the modern sense of *with* was expressed by *mid* (cognate with German *mit*). In the later part of the Old English period, however, northeast England was occupied and to some extent settled by speakers of Old Norse dialects, and over the next centuries (down into the Middle English period) many Old Norse words replaced the corresponding Old English words. For instance, *they* and *are* are of ON origin. Old Norse *við*, a cognate of *with* and *wider*, had approximately the sense of *mid* and *mit*, and under its influence, *with* shifted to the modern sense. However, the old sense lingered in established compounds such as *withstand* (stand against), *withhold* (hold from), *withdraw (draw away from)*—and *within* (against *or* by the inside).